# Actively create Insights Table from Raw table in Bigquery

Tags: sql, data-structures, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I have a raw Table in Bigquery that ingest streaming data from on-prem table. The data can be of 3 types Insert, update or delete so to overcome preforming DML operation I did create the schema with appending creation_timestamp and operation(I,U,D) and insert into Bigquery table in streaming fashion.

Now, I wanted an insight table on top of this raw table that I can get basically using below query so that I can take extracts if required due to which creating views wont help.

```
 select * except(rn, creation_timestamp, operation ) from(select *, row_number() over(partition by <primary_key> order by creation_timestamp desc, operation desc ) rn
    from  <Table_name> )
    where rn =1 and operation!='D'
```

Please suggest a way so that I can get data flowing into Insights table with only active records from Raw table.

Answer (score 1):

Got this problem solved using stored procedures.

I first create a stored procedure with below query

And scheduled it to run using cloud function and cloud schedule for every five minutes.

Note: took 10 min window data from raw table in every 5 min considering creation_timestammp delay than actual data insertion timestamp. Since, creation_timestmap is created another cloud function that is used to store data into raw table.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
  <stored_procedure>()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
  <insights_table>
SELECT
  *
FROM
  <raw_table>
WHERE
  creation_timestamp>current_timesamp-10mins;
DELETE
  <insights_table> outside
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      * EXCEPT(rn )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <primary_key> ORDER BY creation_timestamp DESC, operation DESC ) rn
      FROM
        <insights_table> )
    WHERE
      rn =1
      AND operation!='D') inside
  WHERE
    outside.<primary_key>=inside.<primary_key>
    AND outside.creation_timestamp=inside.creation_timestamp
    AND outside.operation=inside.operation );
END
  ;
```

Please, suggest any better way or improvements with the current approach if there are any.